# How to debug event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

Using Chrome , I need to debug the java-script handler that is executed when a specific button is clicked, without searching the java-script files.

Can I use Chrome's "inspect element" for the button to find java-script handler?
Or, is there a recommended tool?

How to achieve this?

p.s: Think of a complex app within a website, I need to debug the logic behind some buttons..

Answer (score 0):

When you open the developer tools on the element tab if you select the element to debug you will see at your right a tab Event Listener. It is with the Styles tab. there you can inspect the event listener. In my opinion the best way is to add break points on the sources. You'll see.